# Group Alert feature required for WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, web-part

In current web-part (http://advancedalert.codeplex.com/) there is no facility to remove the group alert or who is subscribed to the lisy. Also new members added to the group do not automatically get the alert set for them. It has to be manually done for each new user. Is there an update to this webpart which solves these problems? or a substitute?

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried contacting the author of this web part directly? He may be able to provide you information about any possible updates to the web part.

Jerome Noirfalise: http://www.noirfalise.com/

Comment: Hi, Do you know of any such webpart (free)??